# Confirm a select2 selection

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 v4, and I'm trying to display a `confirm()` when the user selects an option from the dropdown.

So I have the event `.on("select2:select", function(e) {})` and I want to prevent select2 if the users chooses cancel from the confirm dialog.

I have the following:

```
    $("#select2users").select2().on("select2:select", function(e) { 
        var data = e.params.data;

        if(!confirm("Are you sure you want to ban this user?")) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    })
```

`e.preventDefault();` doesn't seem to have any effect here.
I've been searching and cannot achieve any decent answer. 
How should I do it?

Comment: Can you share a live demo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly of me, I achieved it simply by clearing the value if the user cancel's the confirm dialog.

Like so:

```
    $("#select2users").select2().on("select2:select", function(e) { 
        var data = e.params.data;

        if(!confirm("Are you sure you want to ban this user?")) {
            $(this).select2('val', '');
        }
    })
```

Comment: This doesn't prevent change event.